# Convert blank cells to NaN in Excel File

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

When parsing an excel file in Pandas,

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(0, parse_dates=[0, 1])
```

Is there a way to convert all of the blank cells to NaN rather than to 0?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question. Are you sure its giving you 0 rather than NaN? Please specify the input example columns from the excel that you are reading into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
 df = df.replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
```